# Enable 2D Scrolling in an EditText with high number of text line and styles

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, html

I'm trying to create a big multiline EditText, scrollable in 2d mode (such as android browser), without word wrap and that fills the entire activity. This edittext 'll contains high number of text line (even + than 3000) and there'll be some span with different styles such as font color, background color ecc... determined at runtime.
I tried to define the layout with the code below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

The results is a big multiline EditText with vertical scrolling...but horizontal scrolling is not enabled...and word wrap is still active. How can i achieve this? I have also noticed that with long text, and some span styling, vertical scrolling becomes very slow. How can i make it more fluid? I did all my test on an acer iconia a500 that's  good device...

Thank you very much for support and sorry for my english!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I partially solved my problem simply by drawing an HorizontalScrollView nested into a ScrollView in this way, but i'm still having slow scrolling problem with styled spans.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
                        android:singleLine="false" 
                        android:background="@color/White"/>
         </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```